# Create private node

Tags: knife, ibm-cloud-infrastructure

I am trying to figure out how to create a vs on a private node in SoftLayer using the knife softlayer plugin. According to an initial release, it looks like there should be a flag --single-tenant for that purpose (https://sldn.softlayer.com/blog/matteldridge/do-more-less-softlayer-knife-chef) but if you look at the code it's now commented out (https://github.com/softlayer/knife-softlayer/blob/master/lib/chef/knife/softlayer_server_create.rb).
So is there another way to create a vs on private node?
Thanks

Answer (score 1):

they removed that option I sugest you to create an issue here https://github.com/softlayer/knife-softlayer/issues

You can create the VSI on private node using a single rest call see: http://sldn.softlayer.com/reference/services/SoftLayer_Virtual_Guest/createObject

you just need to set the dedicatedAccountHostOnlyFlag as true.

Also you can see all the available configurations to order the VSI using this method http://sldn.softlayer.com/reference/services/SoftLayer_Virtual_Guest/getCreateObjectOptions

Answer (score 0):

```
knife softlayer server create  \
--image-id ${image_id} \
--ssh-keys ${ssh_keys} \
--hostname $node_name \
--network-interface-speed 100 \
--domain $domain_name \
--cores ${cores} \
--ram ${ram} \
--datacenter ${datacenter} \
--node-name $node_name \
--private-vlan $private_vlan \
--use-private-network \
--private-network-only \
-x root \
-i $USER_HOME/.ssh/id_rsa -VV
```

`--private-network-only` option creates the Virtual Server in private network